# Adding pre-publish checks with Gutenberg

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

Before publishing an unpublished article pre-publish checks are shown.

How can I extend this programmatically, and disable the publish button if the checks are not passed?

[image: prepublish check]

Comment: I added an example on how to do this here -https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339138/add-pre-publish-conditions-to-the-block-editor/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This got me started.

Set up the block with `create-guten-block` [Gitub](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block)

Update `block.js` to something like:

```
import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';

var PluginPrePublishPanel = wp.editPost.PluginPrePublishPanel;
var registerPlugin = wp.plugins.registerPlugin;

function Component() {
    wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').lockPostSaving()
    //do stuff
    //wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').unlockPostSaving()
    return wp.element.createElement(
        PluginPrePublishPanel,
        {   
            className: 'my-plugin-publish-panel',
            title: 'Panel title',
            initialOpen: true,
        },  
        'Panel content'
    );  
}

registerPlugin( 'my-plugin', {
  render: Component,
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how WP intends the `pluginPrePublishPanel` to be used, but locking/unlocking post saving directly inside of a function component definitely is not a good way to do it and will lead to bugs.