# Add pre-publish conditions to the block editor

Tags: block-editor

The introduction of the **Block Editor** killed all plugins which offered publishing conditions, such as minimum word counts, featured image requirements etc.

But the Block Editor *did* introduce the **pre-publish checks**:

[image: Pre-publish checks]

Beautiful. How can we disable the `Publish` button until a set amount of conditions have been fulfilled?

Examples of four (very) different conditions:

1. Minimum word count (example: `500` words)
2. Min/max tags (example: `3-5` tags)
3. Min category (that isn't `uncategorized`)
4. Featured image is assigned

### What we have so far

As expected, the documentation is non-existent. But leads are scattered across the web.

In `core/editor`, we can use [.lockPostSaving()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-editor/#lockPostSaving) to disabled the `Publish` button, and unlock it via `.unlockPostSaving()`.

We can add a panel to the pre-publish screen via `PluginPrePublishPanel`. Example (by [MadMaardigan](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/334671/24875)):

```
var PluginPrePublishPanel = wp.editPost.PluginPrePublishPanel;
var registerPlugin = wp.plugins.registerPlugin;

function Component() {
    // lock post saving
    wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').lockPostSaving()

    // unlock post saving
    // wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').unlockPostSaving()

    return wp.element.createElement(
        PluginPrePublishPanel,
        {   
            className: 'my-plugin-publish-panel',
            title: 'Panel title',
            initialOpen: true,
        },  
        'Panel content'
    );  
}

registerPlugin( 'my-plugin', {
  render: Component,
});
```

It works:

[image: Custom pre-publish panel]

And we have great discussions on GitHub: [#7020](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7020), [#7426](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7426), [#13413](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13413), [#15568](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/15568), [#10649](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/10649)...

Comment: It looks like you have the approach nailed down - are you looking for the code that implements this approach?

Comment: @Welcher Yes, absolutely. With the (four) conditions.

Comment: Please check this https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/blog-post-checklists/.
This may help you.

Comment: @Bhupen Thanks, but all plugins listed in that article doesn't work with Gutenberg, beside *perhaps* one, which is a paid plugin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT Sept 2021:**

An updated version of the answer that uses hooks.

This version tracks changes in the editor much better. It also uses `import` statement instead of importing directly from the `wp` global. This approach when used with the `@wordpress/scripts` package will correctly add dependencies for this file when being enqueued. Accessing the `wp` global will still work but you will have to be sure you're managing your script dependencies manually.

Thanks to everyone in the comments!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginPrePublishPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { count } from '@wordpress/wordcount';
import { serialize } from '@wordpress/blocks';

const PrePublishCheckList = () => {
    // Manage the messaging in state.
    const [wordCountMessage, setWordCountMessage] = useState('');
    const [catsMessage, setCatsMessage] = useState('');
    const [tagsMessage, setTagsMessage] = useState('');
    const [featuredImageMessage, setFeaturedImageMessage] = useState('');

    // The useSelect hook is better for retrieving data from the store.
    const { blocks, cats, tags, featuredImageID } = useSelect((select) => {
        return {
            blocks: select('core/block-editor').getBlocks(),
            cats: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('categories'),
            tags: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('tags'),
            featuredImageID:
                select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('featured_media'),
        };
    });

    // The useDispatch hook is better for dispatching actions.
    const { lockPostSaving, unlockPostSaving } = useDispatch('core/editor');

    // Put all the logic in the useEffect hook.
    useEffect(() => {
        let lockPost = false;
        // Get the WordCount
        const wordCount = count(serialize(blocks), 'words');
        if (wordCount < 500) {
            lockPost = true;
            setWordCountMessage(`${wordCount} - Minimum of 500 required.`);
        } else {
            setWordCountMessage(`${wordCount}`);
        }

        // Get the category count
        if (!cats.length || (cats.length === 1 && cats[0] === 1)) {
            lockPost = true;
            setCatsMessage('Missing');
            // Check that the cat is not Uncategorized - this assumes that the ID of Uncategorized is 1, which it would be for most installs.
            if (cats.length === 1 && cats[0] === 1) {
                setCatsMessage('Cannot use Uncategorized');
            }
        } else {
            setCatsMessage('Set');
        }

        // Get the tags
        if (tags.length < 3 || tags.length > 5) {
            lockPost = true;
            setTagsMessage('Required 3 - 5 tags');
        } else {
            setTagsMessage('Set');
        }
        // Get the featured image
        if (featuredImageID === 0) {
            lockPost = true;
            setFeaturedImageMessage('Not Set');
        } else {
            setFeaturedImageMessage(' Set');
        }

        if (lockPost === true) {
            lockPostSaving();
        } else {
            unlockPostSaving();
        }
    }, [blocks, cats, tags, featuredImageID]);

    return (
        <PluginPrePublishPanel title={'Publish Checklist'}>
            <p>
                <b>Word Count:</b> {wordCountMessage}
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>Categories:</b> {catsMessage}
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>Tags:</b> {tagsMessage}
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>Featured Image:</b> {featuredImageMessage}
            </p>
        </PluginPrePublishPanel>
    );
};

registerPlugin('pre-publish-checklist', { render: PrePublishCheckList });
```

**Old Version**:

```
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginPrePublishPanel } = wp.editPost;
const { select, dispatch } = wp.data;
const { count } = wp.wordcount;
const { serialize } = wp.blocks;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;

const PrePublishCheckList = () => {
    let lockPost = false;

    // Get the WordCount
    const blocks = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks();
    const wordCount = count( serialize( blocks ), 'words' );
    let wordCountMessage = `${wordCount}`;
    if ( wordCount < 500 ) {
        lockPost = true;
        wordCountMessage += ` - Minimum of 500 required.`;
    }

    // Get the cats
    const cats = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'categories' );
    let catsMessage = 'Set';
    if ( ! cats.length ) {
        lockPost = true;
        catsMessage = 'Missing';
    } else {
        // Check that the cat is not uncategorized - this assumes that the ID of Uncategorized is 1, which it would be for most installs.
        if ( cats.length === 1 && cats[0] === 1 ) {
            lockPost = true;
            catsMessage = 'Cannot use Uncategorized';
        }
    }

    // Get the tags
    const tags = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'tags' );
    let tagsMessage = 'Set';
    if ( tags.length < 3 || tags.length > 5 ) {
        lockPost = true;
        tagsMessage = 'Required 3 - 5 tags';
    }

    // Get the featured image
    const featuredImageID = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'featured_media' );
    let featuredImage = 'Set';

    if ( featuredImageID === 0 ) {
        lockPost = true;
        featuredImage = 'Not Set';
    }

    // Do we need to lock the post?
    if ( lockPost === true ) {
        dispatch( 'core/editor' ).lockPostSaving();
    } else {
        dispatch( 'core/editor' ).unlockPostSaving();
    }
    return (
        <PluginPrePublishPanel title={ 'Publish Checklist' }>
            <p><b>Word Count:</b> { wordCountMessage }</p>
            <p><b>Categories:</b> { catsMessage }</p>
            <p><b>Tags:</b> { tagsMessage }</p>
            <p><b>Featured Image:</b> { featuredImage }</p>
        </PluginPrePublishPanel>
    )
};

registerPlugin( 'pre-publish-checklist', { render: PrePublishCheckList } );
```

Display:

[image]

The solution above addresses the requirements listed in the question. One thing that can be expanded on is the category checking, I am making some assumptions about the category ID.

I have kept all of the checks in the same component for the sake of brevity and readability here. I would recommend moving each portion into a separate component and potentially making them Higher Order Components ( i.e withWordCount ).

I have inline comments that explain what is being done but am happy to explain further if there are any questions.

EDIT: Here's how I'm enqueuing the script

```
function enqueue_block_editor_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-custom-script', // Handle.
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/build/index.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-edit-post', 'word-count' ) // Dependencies, defined above.
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' );
```

Adding some more details about the build process. I am using [@wordpress/scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts) and running the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start"
  },
```

Edit 2:

You can get the attachment data via:

```
wp.data.select('core').getMedia( ID )
```

Comment: There was a minor issue with the operator for the tags (edited your answer), but works like a charm. I now know how little I know about developing with Gutenberg. Thank you so much for this answer! PS: The reason why it was not displaying originally for me was because users on `contributor` level can't see the pre-publish panel properly, see [this bug report](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16198).

Comment: Update: my bug report is successful and they are [fixing it](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/16424)!

Comment: Locking the post directly in this component is an anti pattern. The `PluginPrePublishPanel` is exactly what it says it is. It's a **panel** to **render** custom things in the sidebar that is shown before publishing. It's not supposed to be the place where you lock/unlock the post saving. Renders should never have this kind of direct effect and doing this will lead to bugs.

Comment: As this is rendered in the last step before publishing is done, I'd argue this is the best place to do it. I'm not sure how this is an anti-pattern either, as the only way to introduce functionality to the BlockEditor is done via SlotFill - so by your logic, anything rendered anywhere cannot do anything but render static content.

Comment: It's an anti-pattern because it's not the moment you want this post locking to happen. A component function is only rerun when its props change (or when it uses custom hooks or state). There may be forced re-renders from time to time, but you can't rely on those keeping on happening. I actually tried your solution on WP 5.6, and the post save button stays disabled after making my post valid again. So I can't trigger the panel to render again. I need to close and re-open the whole sidebar using the cog icon to enable the button, because only then it reruns the validation logic and post locking.

Comment: This code is a little old now. I would probably add a useEffect hook that that unlocked the post when the component unmounted. I would very much be interested in a alternative solution if you have one.

Comment: How would useEffect inside the component solve the problem that the post only gets re-checked when the component gets rendered? As I said, this should not be attached to a component that just happens to be rendered at the right moment. I'm currently trying a subscriber that validates the post whenever it changes, and dispatches the locking/unlocking. I'll post an answer if it works out.

Comment: *"not sure how this is an anti-pattern either, as the only way to introduce functionality to the BlockEditor is done via SlotFill"* This is definitely not the only way to customize the block editor. It's the only way to show custom elements in **slots** in the editor. That doesn't mean it's the only way you can interact with the data in the editor. And even if it was the only way, that doesn't change the fact side effects in render are an anti pattern.

Comment: Good luck! Looking forward to your approach. I’m going to go back to my day. :)

Comment: Before you go back to your day, maybe you can save other people the time and update your answer to say it doesn't work anymore? ;)

Comment: Just to follow up here. I just did a copy and paste with no modifications, did a build and not only did it work as expected but it also unlocked the post when hitting cancel. This was how it was intended to work and seems to be still working as expected. This was on WordPress 5.7.1

Comment: For the benefit of folks coming here and reading the comments, the question requested a solution that renders in the PrePublishPanel and locks publishing at that point. This answer provided that solution - regardless of whether anyone considers this approach an anti-pattern. The approach mentioned by @inwerpsel is a different way of doing this that is not incorrect, but just not what OP requested.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. A few clarifications - was it intentional to make the function name/call the same as the hook: `enqueue_block_editor_assets`? And does this solution require the build process, or should it be working without one?

Comment: Hey @Welcher It does work as expected on first time but after we make changes lets say select few categories but check is not refreshing like inwerpsel mentioned.  Any clue if we can make it working using useEffect to recheck after making changes. ? Thanks

Comment: @HashimAziz - yes the naming was intentional however I can see how it could unclear. I was using the build process process provided by the @wordpress/scripts package.

Comment: @JigneshBhavani thanks for mentioning this! I'll take another look at this today and update the answer if needed.

Comment: @Welcher I created work around by using `wp.subscribe()` method which was allowing me to track new changes on category selector but It doesn't looks convenient as even new post is also showing me Category selection notice which I dispatched along with `lockPostSaving()`. I'm still trying to fix by Prepublish way. Any head start would be great from you :)

Comment: @JigneshBhavani Does the latest version work for you?

Comment: @JigneshBhavani yes it works for me. I recently did a live stream where I took a different approach. Perhaps it will help. You can see it here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHmiI1p26Vc

Comment: @Welcher It does work for me too. Great work although I didn't get a chance to watch the live stream yet. I'll watch this weekend. Keep up the great work mate :)

Comment: @Welcher Beautiful update to this code. I adapted the new version today to a production site and it is working considerably better than the previous version. Very helpful stream as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 29.02.2020**

You have to replace `select( 'core/editor' ).getBlocks()` with `select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks()` in order for this to work

This worked for me:

`path\to\theme\pre-publish-checklist\src\index.js`

```js
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginPrePublishPanel } = wp.editPost;
const { select, dispatch } = wp.data;
const { count } = wp.wordcount;
const { serialize } = wp.blocks;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;

const PrePublishCheckList = () => {
    let lockPost = false;

    // Get the WordCount
    const blocks = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks();
    const wordCount = count( serialize( blocks ), 'words' );
    let wordCountMessage = `${wordCount}`;
    if ( wordCount < 500 ) {
        lockPost = true;
        wordCountMessage += ` - Minimum of 500 required.`;
    }

    // Get the cats
    const cats = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'categories' );
    let catsMessage = 'Set';
    if ( ! cats.length ) {
        lockPost = true;
        catsMessage = 'Missing';
    } else {
        // Check that the cat is not uncategorized - this assumes that the ID of Uncategorized is 1, which it would be for most installs.
        if ( cats.length === 1 && cats[0] === 1 ) {
            lockPost = true;
            catsMessage = 'Cannot use Uncategorized';
        }
    }

    // Get the tags
    const tags = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'tags' );
    let tagsMessage = 'Set';
    if ( tags.length < 3 || tags.length > 5 ) {
        lockPost = true;
        tagsMessage = 'Required 3 - 5 tags';
    }

    // Get the featured image
    const featuredImageID = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'featured_media' );
    let featuredImage = 'Set';

    if ( featuredImageID === 0 ) {
        lockPost = true;
        featuredImage = 'Not Set';
    }

    // Do we need to lock the post?
    if ( lockPost === true ) {
        dispatch( 'core/editor' ).lockPostSaving();
    } else {
        dispatch( 'core/editor' ).unlockPostSaving();
    }
    return (
        <PluginPrePublishPanel title={ 'Publish Checklist' }>
            <p><b>Word Count:</b> { wordCountMessage }</p>
            <p><b>Categories:</b> { catsMessage }</p>
            <p><b>Tags:</b> { tagsMessage }</p>
            <p><b>Featured Image:</b> { featuredImage }</p>
        </PluginPrePublishPanel>
    )
};

registerPlugin( 'pre-publish-checklist', { render: PrePublishCheckList } );
```

Full steps to create the panel with @wordpress/scripts

1. Create a folder `pre-publish-checklist` in your theme
2. Create inside the folder package.json file with

```json
{
 "scripts": {
   "build": "wp-scripts build",
   "check-engines": "wp-scripts check-engines",
   "check-licenses": "wp-scripts check-licenses",
   "format:js": "wp-scripts format-js",
   "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
   "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
   "lint:md:docs": "wp-scripts lint-md-docs",
   "lint:md:js": "wp-scripts lint-md-js",
   "lint:pkg-json": "wp-scripts lint-pkg-json",
   "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
   "start": "wp-scripts start",
   "test:e2e": "wp-scripts test-e2e",
   "test:unit": "wp-scripts test-unit-js"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@wordpress/scripts": "^7.1.2"
 }
}
```

3. Create a file in the folder with the path 'src/index.js' and place the code in the file
4. `yarn`
5. `yarn build`
6. Add this code to functions.php to enqueue the file

```
function enqueue_block_editor_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'pre-publish-checklist', // Handle.
        get_template_directory_uri(). '/pre-publish-checklist/build/index.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-edit-post', 'word-count' ) // Dependencies, defined above.
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' );
```

Comment: You only replaced one instance of `core/editor` with `core/block-editor` in your code. Was this intentional?

Comment: Gutenberg changed over time. @HashimAziz do I need to update the code?

Comment: No, I finally managed to get this working after setting up a build process, the step-by-step instructions helped.