# Gutenberg - Title field required

Tags: jquery, block-editor, title

I'm trying to make the `title` field required in **Gutenberg** editor interface.

The PHP functions I found work with **Classic** editor interface but not with **Gutenberg**.

I tried to add `required` attribute on the textarea field (title) with jQuery but I can still validate the publication of my post.

```
<?php  
function wp_required_title_field() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            jQuery('.editor-post-title textarea').prop('required',true);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action ('in_admin_footer' , 'wp_required_title_field');
?>
```

I tried another way too :

```
<?php  
function force_post_title() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            jQuery('.editor-post-publish-button__button').click(function(){
              var testervar = jQuery('.editor-post-title').find('.editor-post-title__input');
              if (testervar.val().length < 1) {
                  jQuery('.editor-post-title').css('border', '1px solid red');
                  $( '.editor-post-title' ).after('<label>Post title is required</label>'); // Make it red according your requirement
                  return false;
              }
          });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'force_post_title');
add_action('edit_page_form', 'force_post_title');
?>
```

Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I guarantee it's not using jQuery. The new editor is a React application, so you shouldn't be modifying it using jQuery like this. You're likely to just break the whole thing because the HTML of the editor needs to match the internal state of the application, and adding markup with jQuery could mess with that.

Comment: Thank you. I thought to use ACF field required too. Do you think I can change the permalink title with this ACF field ?

Comment: Nothing in your question mentions permalinks. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: If I wanted the title field to be mandatory it was to be sure to have a correct permalink. This is for a project with students. Avoid "untitled" page title in post list and avoid WordPress to use a number in permalink. 
I did not want to complicate the question. From the moment when the title field was required the other problems were solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `PluginPrePublishPanel` to check for the title and lock publishing if it's empty. Have a look at the accepted answer here for an example of locking the post - [Add pre-publish conditions to the block editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339138/add-pre-publish-conditions-to-the-block-editor/339662#339662)

For your example you could modify the checking portion as follows:

```
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginPrePublishPanel } = wp.editPost;
const { select, dispatch } = wp.data;
const { count } = wp.wordcount;
const { serialize } = wp.blocks;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;

const PrePublishCheckList = () => {
    let lockPost = false;
    let message = '';

    // Get title 
    const postTitle = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' );
    if ( postTitle === '' ) {
        lockPost = true;
        message = 'Post Title is required!';
    }


    // Do we need to lock the post?
    if ( lockPost === true ) {
         dispatch( 'core/editor' ).lockPostSaving();
    } else {
         dispatch( 'core/editor' ).unlockPostSaving();
    }
    return (
        <PluginPrePublishPanel title={ 'Publish Checklist' }>
            <p>{message}</p>
        </PluginPrePublishPanel>
    )
};

registerPlugin( 'pre-publish-checklist', { render: PrePublishCheckList }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for you help. This is a new trail for me